# How do I create an artifact with Multi-Value field type?

Tags: rally, pyral

I'm trying to programatically create a User Story in Rally with pyral. We have some custom fields set up, e.g Client Name, which is a Drop-Down List (Multi-Value), for regular fields I'm able to provide the value as {key: value pairs} (e.g {"Priority": "High"}). How do I work with Multi-Value fields?

When I pass string I get "Error 421 Client Name cannot be null", when I pass an array, it doesn't work either.

```
    c_ClientName: {
        _rallyAPIMajor: "2",
        _rallyAPIMinor: "0",
        _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/331721021908/c_ClientName",
        _type: "AllowedAttributeValue",
        _tagsNameArray: [
            {
                Name: "Client one",
                _ref: "/allowedattributevalue/1234567"
            },
            {
                Name: "Client two",
                _ref: "/allowedattributevalue/1234568"
            },
            {
                Name: "Client three",
                _ref: "/allowedattributevalue/1234569"
            }
        ],
        Count: 3
    }
```

This is what a typical read of existing User stories look like.

Comment: Could you please kindly advise what does it mean "Multi-Value field type"?

Comment: Find more documentation about that here: https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/create-custom-fields#multi